# How to print to console in .dll file

Tags: c, r, visual-studio, dll

I am utilizing some C code in R, and when a bit of C code is called in R, I would like for it to bring up the console and print information to it. I have a .dll with a bunch of function statements that are utilized in R. Therefore, whenever R uses one of these C functions, I would like the console to appear. After doing some googling, I found the following code:

```
void displayToConsole(const char *string)
{
    AllocConsole();
    HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "stdoutnot available", "Error", MB_OK);
    }

    if (WriteConsole(h, string, strlen(string), NULL, NULL) == FALSE)
    {
        if (AllocConsole() == TRUE)
        {
            WriteConsole(h, string, strlen(string), NULL, NULL);
            getch();
            FreeConsole();
        }
    }
    else
        getch();

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszCmdline, int nCmdShow)
{
    displayToConsole("Test");

    return 0;
}
};
```

So I threw the `displayToConsole()` function in one of the C functions utilized by R, but I do not see any contents printed to the console. An example of this would be an R function that creates a GUI. Upon initialization of the GUI, I would like to have the console appear and print out information. I may be grossly misunderstanding what am I suppose to be doing here, as I do not have any experience in these topics. How can I actualize the console when calling C functions from a .dll?

Comment: Are you talking about the R console or command line interface of your OS?

Comment: command line of OS

Comment: Ok, I have no idea how to do that, in particular on Windows. I do find it rather unusual, though. Normally an R function is called via the R console, to which on can easily print using `Rfprint()`.